# Local host not displaying file correctly then page crashes, then works (Pictures)

Tags: macos, terminal, localhost, port, jekyll

I am running my jeykll website on my local host. This is my terminal

`jekyll --server $4000 --auto`

Although the some reason when i type localhost:4000 into my browser it doesnt work, i have to go to 337. Does anyone know why?

Anyway when i first load it up it displays as it should.

http://cl.ly/image/390e033s160I

Then i refresh the page

http://cl.ly/image/11470G2z1s15

Another refresh brings this

http://cl.ly/image/3G2m0O3w1Y3x

And it will carry on in a circle everytime.

The website can be found here:
joshhornby.co.uk

Ok a quick look in the chrome dev tools told me this: Failed to load resource `http://localhost:337/stylesheets/style.css`
But why? It loads some of the time? Very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate solution is that the command line should be

```
jekyll --server 4000 --auto
```

4000 is not an environment variable, so no $ is needed.

I usually put the port in the _config.yml - likely that is where the 337 comes from. The other problems could be permissions related - using a port number under 1000 means needing admin access, which can cause problems when regenerating files.